# send key to another application

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to write an app (using java for blackberry phone), which can auto send key to another application. It is similar to type directly into that application. I found ShortcutMe do it very well. Have anyone know how to do that. Help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have no relations with the vendors of the other application, or prior knowledge of which application you will be sending key events to, you will have to use the [Event Injection API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Event_injection_808536_11.jsp).

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try to use "new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, key, 0).post()" and it worked.